# How do I alter the comment form 'allowed tags' text in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, php, comments, filters

I'm using the PHP Markdown plugin, and I'd like to modify it so that it adds some text to the bottom of the comment form indicating that Markdown is supported in comments.

I've been modifying my theme to do this, but the theme is updated quite frequently and I don't want to create a custom version of it for a single line of text to be preserved.

In my `comments.php` file (Theme is ZBench) I have the following:

```
$comment_notes='<p class="comment-note">' . __('NOTE - You can use these ','zbench') . sprintf(('<abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> '.__('tags and attributes:','zbench').'<br />%s' ), ' <code>' . allowed_tags() . '</code>' ) . '</p>';
```

I simply want to add to that indicating Markdown is active, and presumably the ideal way to do that is to alter the output of `allowed_tags()`. Is this possible to do with `add_filter()`, or am I looking at the wrong function?

I want to modify the plugin itself, so that the extra line is added only if the plugin is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go... Use this code:

```
<?php
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'change_allowed_fields');

function change_allowed_fields($defaults) 
{
    //All the comment form fields are available in the $defaults array
    $defaults['comment_notes_after'] = "<b>Markdown for the win!</b>";

    return $defaults;
}
```

This will work!

Comment: That doesn't seem to be altering the output of `allowed_tags()`. I wish the documentation on filters was more up to date :(

Comment: The text at the bottom of the comment form doesn't come from the `allowed_tags()` function, it only specifies the actual tags that are allowed. Your question says `so that it adds some text to the bottom of the comment form indicating that Markdown is supported in comments`, means help text, that's what my code does. Just put this code in your theme's `functions.php` file and it will work.

Comment: I ended up making a `frankenplugin` for this, and several other minor theme tweaks. I'm happy, I don't have to cringe every time a new version of my theme is available :) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome! :) Nice job with the plugin, it's always a good idea to keep all the tweaks in a separate plugin, so that you can use it multiple times, without breaking anything and across updates!

Comment: A relevant link with lots more information for those interested: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/21/using-the-wordpress-comment-form